# Creating table using loop

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

How to creating table using while to put in these table x rows, which will consist row number and the word 'row'.

For example Row1, Row2, Row3, ...

Comment: I would do this in another language, and process an sql string through it's loop functionality, but I cannot see a single reasonable use for this. Whatever you are trying to do, it does not seem like a best practice move. I think you'd be able to get more help if you gave us a short explanation of your goal here, in a seperate paragraph under your question.

Comment: This is my exercise. I do it only for educational purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive CTE:

```
;with t(n) as (
    select 1 union all
    select n + 1 from t where n < 100 --x
)
select 'Row' + cast(n as varchar(8)) as f into NEW_TABLE from T
```

Comment: Can you describe me why 'as f' is required?

Comment: That selects the column into a new table, `as f` gives that column the name `f` - if it wasn't there, what would the column be called?